# How widespread is oomoto-kyo within the Aikido community?

Tags: aikido, mysticism

[Morihei Ueshiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morihei_Ueshiba) was a ardent [oomoto-kyo](http://www.oomoto.or.jp/) follower. Rumours of him bullying his students to check out the religion abound. [Ueshiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morihei_Ueshiba) claimed that [oomoto-kyo](http://www.oomoto.or.jp/) was inextricably linked to him developing Aikido.

How effective was the spread of [oomoto-kyo](http://www.oomoto.or.jp/) within Aikido?

In [shodokan Aikido](http://en.shodokanaikido.com/), you would be hard pressed to see any evidence of the religion as far as I can gather despite [Tomiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenji_Tomiki) dabbling in [oomoto-kyo](http://www.oomoto.or.jp/) at [Ueshiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morihei_Ueshiba)'s advice. But other style (ki-aikido, I am looking at you) might be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in an Aikikai federation and I have not seen any evidence of it.  We have a senior student who will read some of Ueshiba's teachings in that area before we start class but that is really the extent of it.

Comment: Not a universal answer, but definitely one for someone on the ground.